# Assembly XMM registers 8 to 15

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sse, machine-code

For some more optimized memory functions I am looking to utilize the `XMM8` to `XMM15` registers as that would mean I could move more data per loop. However, Intel insinuates different behaviors with these registers. I failed to find any weird bugs in my code to that regard but I am unsure if there might be any dangers laying around the corner. Intel states the following in their [documentation:](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf)

```
XMM8 through XMM15 are available using REX.R in 64-bit mode.
```

To which I only have one questions, what is REX.R?

Comment: Keep reading the vol.2 manual about REX prefixes.

Comment: So its just a 64 bit prefix required for certain operations?

Comment: REX is a 1-byte prefix (that exists only in 64-bit mode), and yes it's required for accessing XMM8..15 and/or r8..r15.  And/or 64-bit operand-size.

Comment: Ah I see. That does make sense. I suppose NASM already handles this but good to know nonetheless. Thanks!